# Text output for mutually exclusive radio buttons R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny, radio-button

Overall context: I am trying to build a decision tree app in shiny and have never used shiny before. I am trying to have text display when a certain radio button is selected. After trial and error I still can't get anything to display with different inputs. Below is the basic code.

```
library(shiny)

priceChange <- "Does it change the price?"
zpInfer1 <- "Can zero-price-change be inferred?"

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("exist", "Does it exist?",
               c("Yes" = "existYes",
                 "No" = "existNo"),
               textOutput("a")
  )
  
)


server <-   function(input, output){
  output$a <- renderText({ 
    existAnswer <- switch(input$exist,
                    existYes = priceChange,
                    existNo = zpInfer1)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: `textOutput()` can't be inside `radioButtons()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Phil said, this seems to be a simple syntax error. This one should work :

```
library(shiny)

priceChange <- "Does it change the price?"
zpInfer1 <- "Can zero-price-change be inferred?"

ui <- fluidPage(
  radioButtons("exist", "Does it exist?",
               c("Yes" = "existYes",
                 "No" = "existNo")),
               textOutput("a")
  
)


server <-   function(input, output){
  output$a <- renderText({ 
    existAnswer <- switch(input$exist,
                          existYes = priceChange,
                          existNo = zpInfer1)
    
    
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```